# Using morph targets with multiple meshes

Tags: mesh, shape-keys

I have meshes from a game that uses morph targets. They are all obj. Files, and I have no clue how to use morph targets. One mesh will be totally ordinary, and then the next one has its mouth open. They have over 10 different meshes with 1 change, and the original mesh uses to move. Can anyone tell me how to successfully use these targets to get the results I need? Is there anyway to save those changes as shapekeys?

-thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can 'join as shapes' two meshes, as long as they have equal number of vertices.

Select first the model with the morph and then the base model (shift+click); in the Shapes Keys panel click the arrow (triangle) and select 'Join as Shapes'.

[image: join as shapes 1]

This will create a Basis key, if the model doesn't have one already, and a key named as the source model (by default is set to 0, I set it to 1 in the image to show the result).

[image: join as shapes 2]