# How to align the vertices of one object with the same vertices of another object?

Tags: modeling

If say you created a sphere (A), and moved its vertices around. Could you create another sphere (B), same as the original, and have B match its vertices with the altered vertices of A? 
If this is possible, how would you do it?

Comment: It all depends on what the intended use is so there are many options: Join as shapes (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68156/using-morph-targets-with-multiple-meshes and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75124/blender-morphing-object-shape), Link the geometry (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86900/how-can-i-link-the-mesh-data-of-several-objects-so-they-all-use-the-same/86904#86904) or use shrinkwrap (like at the bottom of this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60976/1853)

Comment: It looks like linking geometry would serve the purpose I'm looking for, thanks!